# Wait for a character from input for 10 seconds or proceed earlier if a key was pressed?

Tags: java, input, console, delay

I have a Java client-server application, and client gets input from a player through console. It should give the player 10 seconds to press a key, and proceed earlier if the player does so earlier. Also it finishes the round if there was no input.
I googled the problem and there are totally different things that come up and most of them seem to be overcomplicating the small task. I am also unable to choose what is most suitable for this as I haven't done anything similar before.
So, should I:

- use two separate threads,
- use wait() or notify(),
- use sleep(),
- check timestamp or something else?

I would prefer to use a while loop that has two exit conditions.
At the moment I am reading the character input with a scanner like this:

```
 scanner.next().charAt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

For now I did it this way, but advice is still welcome :) I wonder if it is possible not to make the user press "enter" and only read one symbol. With `read()` instead of `readline()` it still waits for an enter to be pressed.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
System.out.print("Time left to bet:  ");
    for (i = 10; i > 0 && !gotInput; i--) {
        System.out.print(i+"...");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        gotInput = reader.ready();
    }
    if (!gotInput) {
        System.out.print(0);
    }
    System.out.println();
```

Comment: Isn't the Thread.sleep going to block all input while the thread is asleep since you're calling it on the same thread that reads in the characters? Why not either use a `java.util.Timer` or a background Thread to solve this without blocking the thread that receives input? Surely your searches have shown you how to use these, since this is a very common problem.

Comment: It checks every other second if there is input. I guess it does block, but it doesn't really matter if the action gets to be done a few milliseconds later. But I'll look into how to use the timer, thanks.